# When using osascript (Javascript) how do I sent console.log messages to standard out

Tags: macos, javascript-automation

If I have this simple little comamnd

```
osascript -l JavaScript -e "console.log('hello')" > file.txt
```

I see the message on the terminal.  However, it is not sent to file.txt.   Any ideas on how to send osascript output to stdout?

Comment: You're redirecting the output of `osascript`, not of the `console.log()` call.  You might also try appending `2>&1` to get both STDOUT and STDERR going to the same file.

Comment: @MarcWilson Did you try with `2>&1`?

Comment: I think @MarcWilson means `osascript -l JavaScript -e "console.log('hello')" > file.txt 2>&1`. Which I did try.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Ah, right, placed the redirection in the wrong spot when I tried.

Comment: @nohillside: `hello` is being written to `stderr`. The same is true for `osascript -e 'log "hello"'`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yeah, got that. But I tried `osascript -l JavaScript -e "console.log('hello')" 2>&1 > file.txt` which doesn't work...

Comment: @nohillside: Maybe this is a better explanation. If I correct what you posted, I get this `{ osascript -l JavaScript -e "console.log('hello')" 2>&1; } > file.txt`, which does work. Now the redirects go from right to left instead of the default, which is left to right.